# How to get all events in vuejs in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

In fullcalendar document , They give example for getting all events in javascript or jquery. But I could not find in vuejs(https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents)

Please any one give example of get all events in vuejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer

use ref on component

`<FullCalendar schedulerLicenseKey="GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source"
:events="events"
:businessHours="businessHours"
ref="calendar" />`

and add this on your method

```
let calendarApi = this.$refs.calendar.getApi();

console.log(calendarApi.getEvents())
```